# Exception is thrown when running flutter app, on assembleDebug Task. Tries to read file from non existing path that's not specified anywhere

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, flutter-dependencies

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20arP.png)

```
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
E/flutter ( 6095): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/
```

This started happening out of nowhere, after the exception is thrown, the task still runs and when the app eventually launches, it's just a blank screen. The path in the error doesn't exist, I don't think I have any mention of said path in my code as the app ran just fine yesterday.

I've tried running flutter clean and flutter pub get, flutter pub upgrade to no avail.

The only code that reads the file in the error output is this and it only runs once in the entire program, in the main function.

```
class NiveisComida{
  static final NiveisComida _singleton = NiveisComida._internal();
  static Map<String,bool> nivel1 = {},nivel2 = {},nivel3 = {};

  static void _readNiveis() async {
    for(int i = 1;i<=3;i++){
      List<String> content = (await rootBundle.loadString('_ficheiros_extra/nivel$i.comida')).split('\n');
      Map<String,bool> aux ={};
      for(String linha in content){
        bool val = true;
        if(linha.contains(';bad')) val = false;
        aux.putIfAbsent(linha, () => val);
      }
      switch(i){
        case 1:
          nivel1 = aux;
          break;
        case 2:
          nivel2 = aux;
          break;
        case 3:
          nivel3 = aux;
          break;

      }
    }
  }

  factory NiveisComida() {
    _readNiveis();
    return _singleton;
  }

  NiveisComida._internal();
}

main.dart


void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  //NiveisComida(); //inicializar lista de niveis de comida
  Intl.defaultLocale = 'pt_PT';
  if(kIsWeb){
    runApp(funcaoMain());
  }else{
    initializeDateFormatting().then((_)=>runApp(funcaoMain()));
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - _ficheiros_extra/nivel1.comida
    - _ficheiros_extra/nivel2.comida
    - _ficheiros_extra/nivel3.comida
    - _ficheiros_extra/comidas.csv
    - _ficheiros_extra/
    - _ficheiros_extra/app_store_badges/
```

_ficheiros_extra/ file structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── _ficheiros_extra
│   ├── alcool.csv
│   ├── app_store_badges
│   │   ├── apple-badge-tamanho-igual.png
│   │   ├── apple-badge.png
│   │   └── google-play-badge.png
│   ├── comidas.csv
│   ├── nivel1.comida
│   ├── nivel2.comida
│   └── nivel3.comida
├── analysis_options.yaml
├── android
│   ├── app
```

If it helps I'm running on a M1 Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by simply rebooting the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Your error said that your code try to load `assets/nivel1.comida` that not exists. Because the right path is `_ficheiros_extra/nivel1.comida`. Make sure the path in your code contains `_ficheiros_extra`. You can print your path before loading to make sure it.

Comment: but there's no assets folder. the code does indeed use `_ficheiros_extra/` and nothing more

Comment: Ok, so you need to load path `_ficheiros_extra/nivel1.comida` and your error said that your code try to load `assets/nivel1.comida`.

Comment: @MartinhoTavares, can you print the file path before you load it? Is the path is `_ficheiros_extra/nivel1.comida`?

Comment: I updated the post with a more complete path. I've also tried to search for the `assets/nivel1.comida` string in the entire directory and there is no occurrence of it. Also tried creating a new project and copying over pubspec, lib/ and _ficheiros_extra/ and it still gave me the error. It's weird since it's reading the file even though I've commented the code that reads such file and also removed the files from pubspec

Comment: Also updated the code with the full class and main(), the only other reference to the NiveisComida class is a read to one of its maps, happens only after the main function.

Comment: @MartinhoTavares sure, there is no `assets/nivel1.comida`. Why your error code said that it try to load `assets/nivel1.comida` and caused an error? Even your actual code try to load right path `_ficheiros_extra/nivel$i.comida`. Is comida.dart line 203 is this code `List<String> content = (await rootBundle.loadString('_ficheiros_extra/nivel$i.comida')).split('\n');`?

Comment: that's what prompted the question ahaha, i genuinely can't find any reference to that path. It also doesn't make sense for the app to load a file during the build stage, or at least I don't know that flutter does that when building

Comment: Have you cleaned it up and rebuild?

Comment: yes, i even made a whole new project, nothing worked

Comment: I've tried in my project to load string from `.comida` file extension and worked. Your new project gives same error? You need to try in another pc/laptop.

Comment: I mean the problem wouldn't be the file extension, it's just a regular text file, it was to make them standout. But I just solved it lol, it was the android emulator, tried a different one, and the error was gone, just need to reboot the first emulator